# How can I download multiple gifs from a website and store it into my directory?

Tags: python

```py
# This is my URL Finallist examples:
URLfinallist = [
  'https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/resources/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/up-lgflag.gif',
  'https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/resources/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/us-lgflag.gif']

first = URLfinallist[0]

response = requests.get(first).content
with open("newtext.gif", "wb") as f:
    f.write(response)
```

So the first one works completely fine, I get the gif, it looks good. However, I am needing to go through all of the links in the list, and then write it to my directory or store it in a file. I have no idea how to do that. Here is me trying:

```py
for line in URLfinallist:
    resp = requests.get(line).content
with open("newtext.gif", "wb") as f:
    f.write(resp)
```

However, this just writes one of the gifs, not all. I need all of them in a file, or in my directory. Any idea on how to write several files and put it in my directory or folder?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? It seems like you need a Python tutorial, which Stack Overflow is not a substitute for.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `open` block is not in the `for` loop. So it only writes the last one.

Also you need to create different filenames for them so they don't overwrite each other. You can do this by setting the filename to the filename from the url. You can get it by splitting the url on slashes and taking the last element (for example, this would give you up-lgflag.gif for the first one).

This would work:

```
for line in URLfinallist:
    resp = requests.get(line).content
    with open(line.split("/")[-1], "wb") as f:
        f.write(resp)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be like this

```
import requests
URLfinallist = ['https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/resources/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/up-lgflag.gif',
                'https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/resources/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/us-lgflag.gif']

for item in URLfinallist:
    with open("{}".format(item.split('/')[-1]), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(item).content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [dload](https://pypi.org/project/dload/) for this kind of tasks:

```
import dload

URLfinallist = ['https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/resources/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/up-lgflag.gif', 'https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/resources/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/us-lgflag.gif']
dload.save_multi(URLfinallist, "./")
```

The gifs will be saved to the script dir.